# Is there any way to use switch statements for user input? C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm a beginner so I apologize if this is a dumb question. I just want to reduce the number of if, else if, and else statements and just make it so that it uses switch statements or something. I tried using switch statements but it seems they can't use ConsoleKey variables.

I want something like this basically

```
var userIn = Console.ReadKey().Key;
switch (userIn)
{
   case ConsoleKey.X: //If user input is X
     //Do smthn
     break;
   case ConsoleKey.Z:
     //Do smthn
   break;
     default:
     //Smthn
     break;
}
```

Again, I'm still a beginner so yeah

First I tried writing case :, but that didn't work.
Then I tried storing ConsoleKey.Y and other inputs in a variable and then writing case , but that doesn't work.

It shows these errors,

> Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case ConsoleKey.Y:') to anotherCS0163
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ConsoleKey' to 'System.ConsoleKeyInfo'CS0029

Here is what I tried:
The code is basically to interact with objects in a jail cell.

```
var jCellIntyuio = Console.ReadKey();
            switch(jCellIntyuio)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Y:
                    jcToilet.ObjInfo(); //Method which gives info on object
                case ConsoleKey.U:
                    WashBasin.ObjInfo();
                case ConsoleKey.I:
                    BunkBed.ObjInfo(); //Method which gives info on object
                case ConsoleKey.U:
                    JailWalls.ObjInfo();
            }
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you tried things?

Comment: ["it's not working" is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: `ConsoleKeyInfo` is a struct, that contains some information about pressed key. Not only key by itself, but its char and used modifiers (like Ctrl or Alt). So if you switch-casing `Key` - your `var jCellIntyuio` must be `Console.ReadKey().Key`

Comment: Microsoft Documentation:
- [Console.ReadKey Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-7.0#system-console-readkey)
- [ConsoleKeyInfo Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo?view=net-7.0)
- [ConsoleKey Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekey?view=net-7.0)

Comment: "Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case ConsoleKey.Y:') to anotherCS0163" - You're missing a `break;` between cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write "jCellIntyuio.Key" to the switch, also you should add break and default parameters. Code should be like this;

```
switch (jCellIntyuio.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.Y:
                jcToilet.ObjInfo(); break; //Method which gives info on object
            case ConsoleKey.U:
                WashBasin.ObjInfo(); break;
            case ConsoleKey.I:
                BunkBed.ObjInfo(); break;//Method which gives info on object
            case ConsoleKey.U:
                JailWalls.ObjInfo(); break;
            default: break;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the issue!

Comment: Could you approve the answer?